# Vulcanize with polymer in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, polymer

Right now i am facing problem if i use vulcanize package with polymer from [here](https://atmospherejs.com/differential/vulcanize). Although this is working perfectly in localhost but not in production server.

I have tried [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/concatenating-web-components.html) also but no luck.

Anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [meteor-vulcanize](https://github.com/Differential/meteor-vulcanize), it might help. You can also refer to this [github repo](https://github.com/Differential/polymer-demo) that shows how to use Polymer with MeteorJS.

If it does not help kindly elaborate more on the exact problem you are facing - error message etc.

Comment: I have tried both the links. On my production server i am getting error  "Uncaught TypeError: Polymer is not a function"